# How to use python markdown to process a file that is read in?

Tags: python, python-2.7, markdown

I have a file myfile.txt.

## hello

And I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import markdown

f = open('myfile.txt', 'r') 
f.read() 
htmlmarkdown=markdown.markdown(f)
```

I got the:

> AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'strip'

What I should do to make a success?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
f = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
htmlmarkdown=markdown.markdown( f.read() )
```

Comment: it works!  thank you!  but could explain the difference? f.read() within markdown and outside it.....

Answer (score 4):

pyDog's answer is correct. Your problem is that f is a file object. You need to pass markdown a string. Calling just f.read() will put the file cursor at the end of the file but won't put the file contents in a string like you need.

```
f = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
fileString = f.read()
htmlmarkdown=markdown.markdown( fileString )
```

If you look at the error you got:

```
 AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

This is because you passed a 'file' object (namely f) to markdown and it tried to call the string function strip() which has no meaning for 'file' objects.